# Automatic Login on Loki will not work

Tags: release-loki, greeter

I've installed Loki and toggled the "Log in Automatically" switch on. But when I restart the system, it still shows the standard log in screen and asks for the password. When I go back to User Accounts, it is still toggled on. So it says to be working, but not. `lightdm.conf` just has:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=sdwhwk
```

user is an admin.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#Enabling_autologin), your user must be part of the "autologin" group.

1. `sudo groupadd -r autologin`
2. `sudo gpasswd -a sdwhwk autologin`

Comment: Thanks. Been a long while working with Linux. I have a lot of refreshing to do.