# Autologin doesn't work (resets after restart)

Tags: security

Installed the last version of Elementary OS, updated. Setup in Users and accounts autologin (don't ask for password when system starts). Reboot the laptop, OS asks me for the password. Check settings and the checkbox is off for autologin. Turn it on. Reboot. Again asks for the password.

Any ideas?

```
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15572/automatic-login-on-loki-will-not-work
```

Tried. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do so using command line.

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and thereafter, add the following lines,

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=<YOUR USERNAME>
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```